# C#, wrap an Action with arguments to an Action without parameters, without using closure

Tags: c#, closures, anonymous-function

How can I avoid using closure to wrap an Action with arguments to one that doesn't take parameters, without the overhead of closures.

For example whats a more performant way to achieve this anonymous method, where SomeAction (arg1, arg2) forms a closure.

```
Action wrappedAction = () => SomeAction(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what closures are for! Is this really a performance bottleneck in your program? Why do you think that this code would perform badly?

Comment: isn't a display class with a copy of the entire object state created to back it?

Comment: The compiler creates a class, yes. But instantiating the closure object at runtime is extremely fast. And the closure doesn't *copy* the captured variables. The compiler has already 'hoisted' the relevant variables to the heap (if necessary), so the closure simply grabs references to these hoisted variables. The process at runtime will most likely involve 1 *extremely fast* managed heap allocation (to create the new closure object), and the copying of 2 references (a few bytes) to use in the underlying method call when the delegate is invoked. That's it.

Comment: Profile your code - if your application is performing badly, I'm willing to bet this is *not* the bottleneck!

Comment: (Note also that managed heap allocation is almost as fast as stack allocation in most cases - and much faster than an equivalent *unmanaged* allocation) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: forgot to say thanks!